# Using ImageButtons to edit/store data for that specific object

Tags: android

so I'm a very new to the android development so please bear with me. I am attempting to create an app that will connect with a database of course listings for students and allow them to select their degree and choose their required courses and which semesters to take them in.

I would like to know how to allow a user to select an ImageButton (which is essentially a course), have it call another activity where they can edit the course information based off of information from the database, and have it return to the original activity with the information for that button stored into it. If anyone can help regarding how I can even approach this that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I certainly recommend learning the UI and the database aspects of Android separately before you try to integrate them. First, you should work out how to create Button `OnClickListner`s, make them call other Activities, learn Activity life cycle and so on. Then you could start looking at how Android works with SQLite. And only then you should try to integrate the two. IMO, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setOnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) to bind a click listener to your button. Use [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen)/`setResult`/`onActivityResult` to start the next activity/return data/handle data. Here's an older tutorial about [doing that](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=302).